# Why cant resize a D Series Azure box to a Dv2 Series box

Tags: virtual-machine, azure

Im trying to resize my azure virtual machine instance to a Dv2, current its a standard D11 instance size. When i select the size in settings all the Dv2 instances are saying not available, but for some of my other virtual machines they are available. Here is a pic of what im seeing:

[image]

There's no real difference between the boxes that can be updated to v2 and the one that cant. Is there anything im missing?

Comment: This is probably off-topic here, as it deals purely with an external service. I'm not sure if there's an SE site that's really appropriate for Azure questions... *possibly* [webapps.se].

Comment: Also, you might find it useful to read this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/resize-virtual-machines/ -- most likely either not available in your region *or* not available in the hardware cluster your VM is currently hosted in.

Comment: If possible you can stop your virtual machine and then resize. Some sizes could not  resize to when the virtual machine was running.

Answer (score 3):

This is affected by which host cluster your VM is running on.  When a VM is powered up you can only select sizes supported on the current cluster.  To move off that cluster, you must deallocate the VM first, then select the new size.

On rare occurrences I've seen where VM sizes are still not available. But I found you can sometimes move to a size that you don't want (something much larger or smaller) which forces a move to a new host cluster, then re-size again to the intended size.

The last method, I've used is to deallocate and delete the VM (keep the disks and NIC's) and just create a new VM configuration with the required size and attach the existing disks and NIC's again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to Stop the VM first through Portal or PowerShell.
Please refer to documentation on link below.

[Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/restart-resize-error-troubleshooting#issue-error-when-resizing-an-existing-vm)